# I am looking for an HTML parser that can replace the "small" tag with "span"'s

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my code that parses the HTML and replaces occurances of the `<small>` tag with `<span>`'s

```
String html =
        "<html>"+
        "<body bgcolor=''>"+
                "<table class='tabletext'>" +
                "<tr align='center' style='background:#FFFFFF'>" +
                "<td class='classa'><span id='fd'><span>10</span></span></td>" +
                "<td>10.00</td>" +
                "<td><small>&pound;0.00</small></td>" +
                "<td>&pound;280.00</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<ul>"+
                "<li><a href=''>ok</a></li>"+
                "</ul>"+
                "<a href='/cart.php?action=add&qty=10&id=2628' title='Click here to add this item to your cart'>" +
                "<img alt='Click here to add this item to your cart' src='/images/addtocart.gif' border='0' />" +
                "</a>" +
                "</td>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr><td><span>Hello2</span></td></tr>"+
                "</table>"+
                "</body>"+
                "</html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);


        Elements elements = doc.select("small");


        Element element2 = elements.get(0);
        System.out.println(element2.replaceWith("<span>"));
```

But the above code is not working properly.

Comment: Btw. instead of `elements.get(0)` you can use `first()` Method: `elements.first()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace all the `<small>` tags with `<span>` you should use [`Node.replaceWith`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#replaceWith%28org.jsoup.nodes.Node%29) correctly.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
for (Element small: doc.select("small")) {
  small.replaceWith(new Element(Tag.valueOf("span"), "").text(small.text()));
}
System.out.println(doc.html()); // prints html with <small> replaced by <span>
```

Comment: If your document has set a `baseUri` you should use `doc.createElement("span")` insteand of `new Element(...)`, because the `createElement(...)` adds the uri of the document to the new element.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is renaming the tag:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("small").tagName("span");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for all tags:

```
Document html=Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
html.select("small").tagName("span");
```